# character and date variable chart

Tags: r, plot

I have a data set that looks like these two first columns are just IDs and the last is the date,
I need to find a relation between them in R but am lost since my first problem is how to visualize my data correctly. I have the id as a factor but each time that I do a plot it gives me a numeric value of that.

[image]

Comment: A relationship with datetime? As in changes in time? What are these ID's?

Comment: Ids representing customer Ids in two different levels, meaning the first id get information on the second iD

Comment: the task is to predict how many ids when would be asked

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain what the first two columns represent, what are these values?

Comment: as i mentioned in the top there are ID 's :customer number like.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. If these are just id's then there is no relationship to be had, since these are random labels. Or are you saying that the labels and their ordering somehow matters?

Comment: my task is to find out if there is a relation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might start visualizing the relationship between your variables using the `pairs.panel` from the `psych` package. Here is an output using the sample data you shared. Note the data points are sparse but you have more data points.

```r
library(psych)
pairs.panels(df)
```

## Output

[image: pairs_panel]

## Data

```r
structure(list(id1 = structure(c(6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
3L), .Label = c("10017097", "17596277", "20501146", "3603827", 
"57106539", "7596227"), class = "factor"), id2 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("10122", "10197", "13840"
), class = "factor"), t_date = structure(c(17966, 17590, 17956, 
17984, 17478, 17483, 17513, 17544), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

The documentation is available at [pairs.panels](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.8.12/topics/pairs.panels)
.